EC2 - auto-tag aws userName on resources with CloudCustodian
What role am I missing?
2024-08-20 16:36:17,763: custodian.policy:INFO Provisioning policy lambda: ec2-auto-tag-user region: us-west-2
2024-08-20 16:36:18,003: custodian.serverless:INFO Publishing custodian policy lambda function custodian-ec2-auto-tag-user
2024-08-20 16:36:18,174: custodian.output:ERROR Error while executing policy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/policy.py", line 587, in provision
    return manager.publish(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/mu.py", line 391, in publish
    result, changed, existing = self._create_or_update(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/mu.py", line 516, in _create_or_update
    result = self.client.create_function(**params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1021, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.
2024-08-20 16:36:18,175: custodian.commands:ERROR Error while executing policy ec2-auto-tag-user, continuing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/commands.py", line 308, in run
    policy()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/policy.py", line 1386, in __call__
    resources = mode.provision()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/policy.py", line 587, in provision
    return manager.publish(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/mu.py", line 391, in publish
    result, changed, existing = self._create_or_update(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/mu.py", line 516, in _create_or_update
    result = self.client.create_function(**params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1021, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.
2024-08-20 16:36:18,179: custodian.commands:ERROR The following policies had errors while executing
 - ec2-auto-tag-user


create a new role called custodian-auto-tagger of entity type "AWS service" with use case of "lambda".   Add the permission of "AWSCloudTrail_FullAccess"
